# Unobtrusive validation ignoring data-val attributes, but working with class="required"

Tags: jquery, html, razor, jquery-validate, unobtrusive-validation

I have the following view:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <div class="left-column">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Expression)
        @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.Expression, new { @spellcheck = "false" })
        @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Sku)
    </div>
}
```

With the following JavaScript which runs every second on a timer:

```
$("form").validate();

if ($("form").valid()) {
    //...
}
```

Generates the following html for the text area element (the only element needing validation):

```
<textarea 
    data-val="true"
    data-val-required="The Expression field is required."
    cols="20" rows="2"
    id="Expression" name="Expression"
    spellcheck="false">
</textarea>
```

The problem is that validation doesn't do anything, unless i manually add class="required" using browser tools. If i do this validation works and the error message "The Expression field is required" is displayed. To be precise "$("form").valid()" always returns true even when textarea is empty.
Since i'm using anotations which automatically generate the data-val attributes, i'd like to rely on those. What am i doing wrong?

FYI my script refs look like this:

```
<script src="/Scripts/modernizr-2.0.6-development-only.js" ...
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.6.2.js" ...
<script src="/Scripts/Parser.js" ...
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js" ...
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.js" ...
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js" ...
```

Comment: Occurs in both Chrome and IE9, my doctype is <!DOCTYPE html>

Comment: Is your form given the id `#paserForm`? Also, ASP.NET MVC should be calling `validate` for you, you shouldn't call it yourself.

Comment: Yes it is, but in fact, the actual JS code runs simply on $("form"), explicitly calling it parserForm was just for a test to see if it changed anything. Same goes for .validate()

Answer (score 1):

Have you enabled Unobtrusive Javascript and Client Validation for .NET?

Try setting the following in your view:

```
@{  Html.EnableUnobtrusiveJavaScript(true);
    Html.EnableClientValidation(true);
    Html.ValidationSummary(true);   
}
```

You can also set it sitewide in your web.config

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
</appSettings>
```

Comment: I have! Well, I don't remember doing it, but it's there, so I'm assuming NuGet did it. Still, this is the first suggestion in almost a month to a problem that's still unresolved so thanks for that!